# Properly loading ruby modules in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I have a file in `lib/acts_as_votable.rb`, it's just a votable system for the app.

```
module ActsAsVotable

end

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    class << self
      cattr_accessor :votable

      def acts_as_votable
        has_many :votes, :as => :voteable
      end

      def votable?
        method_defined? :votes
      end
    end

    def votable?
      self.class.send(:method_defined?, :votes)
    end
  end
end
```

But it seems that the module never loads:

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_votable' for #<Class:0x00000101796d80>
```

What would be the proper way to load modules?

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails 3, as far as I know, doesn't preload files from `lib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put your extensions in the `config/initializers` directory, so they will be preloaded by Rails automatically.

Comment: I think it is. ` Rails turns to loading initializers. An initializer is any file of ruby code stored under /config/initializers in your application. You can use initializers to hold configuration settings that should be made after all of the frameworks and plugins are loaded.` from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that the OP's desired functionality is related to configuration. To load files within /lib you can add the following to /config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/)
```